# Div is not updated after selecting value on a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm trying to display a chart upon selecting a state and a city.

The cities dropdown list is populated based on the selection of the state in the first dropdown.

The problem is when I click on a city no chart is displayed, nor updated if I change the selection, and I can't seem to figure out the problem.

I'm using ChartKick to display a pie chart with the values given by a query in the controller.

My code is as follows:

controllers/city_stats_controller.rb:

```
def city_stats
  @state = params[:state]
  @cities = City.where(:state => @state).select(:id, :display_name).uniq.order('display_name ASC')
  # @city_id = City.select('id').where(:state => params[:city_state]).where(:name => params[:city_name])
  @city_id = City.select('id').find_by_id(params[:city])

  dynamic_query = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ['SELECT COALESCE(name) as name, count(*) FROM (SELECT name, regs.segment_id, count(*) FROM regs
    INNER JOIN segments ON regs.segment_id = segments.id
    WHERE regs.city_id = ?
    GROUP BY segment_id, name
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC) as tabe
    GROUP BY name;', @city_id])

  @spatial_ratio = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(dynamic_query)

  puts @city_id.inspect #I can see the value printed in the terminal
  puts @spatial_ratio.inspect #Same here, even after changing the selection

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @cities }
    format.js {
      render json: {
        html: render_to_string(
          partial: 'city_stats',
          locals: {
            city_id: @city_id,
            spatial_ratio: @spatial_ratio
          })
      }
    }
    format.html
  end
end
```

views/city_stats/city_stats.html.erb :

```
<div class="row">
    <label>State <span>:</span></label>
    <%= collection_select :city, :state, City.select(:state).uniq.order('state ASC'), :state, :state, {:prompt => 'Select a State'}, {id: 'city_state', multiple: false} %> 
    <label>City <span>:</span></label>
    <%= collection_select :city, :name, [], :name, :name, {:prompt => 'Select a City'}, {id: 'city_name', multiple: false} %>
</div>
<div id="cities">
 <!-- Here I render the cities list upon selecting a state-->
 <%= render :partial => 'city_stats', :object => @cities %>
</div>

<div id="stats">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#city_state").on('change', function(){
  $.ajax({
   url: "/admin/city_stats",
   type: "GET",
   data: {state: $(this).val()},
   success: function(data) {
    $("#city_name").children().remove();
    // Create options and append to the list
    var listitems = []; 
    $.each(data,function(key, value) { 
      listitems += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.display_name + '</option>';    
    });  
    $("#city_name").append(listitems);

    //console.log(listitems);

    $("#city_name").on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/admin/city_stats",
      type: "GET",
      data: {city: $(this).val()},
      success: function(data) {
        var content = $("#city_name").val()
        console.log(content);
        $('#stats').replaceWith("<%= j render(partial: 'city_stats') %>");
        return content;

      }
    })

  })
  }
})

});
});
```

And in the partial : views/city_stats/_city_stats.html.erb :

```
<%= pie_chart @spatial_ratio.rows %>
```

***N.B : If I replace the city_id in the dynamic query in the controller by a random id manually, a chart is displayed of the corresponded city when I refresh the page, but I don't know why it's not working dynamically***

Comment: Is your click event on city working? . I mean when you change city, is it hitting server.?

Comment: Hi @krishnar thanks again for your answer! Yes when I change the city I can see the new city_id in Terminal, as well as on the browser's console

Comment: sorry for late response. Can you my check solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.update your city_stats method like below**

```
def city_stats
  ...
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
   format.json  { render :json => @cities } 
   format.js
  end
end
```

**2. create city_stats.js.erb file with below code**

```
$("#stats").html("<%= escape_javascript(pie_chart @spatial_ratio.rows) %>");
```

**3. change your city_click event like this**

```
  $("#city_name").on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/admin/city_stats",
      type: "GET",
      data: {city: $(this).val()},
      success: function(data) {
      }
    })
  });
```

*This should solve your problem. If any problem/doubt comment*

Comment: Thanks a lot @krishnar for your help.. It still hasn't solved my issue, nothing is displayed on the view once I select a city :/

Comment: @GeoSal invite me to chat. will discuss to solve your problem

Comment: I don't think I have enough reputation to start a chat, could you please invite me?

Comment: Following our discussion, just had to add dataType: "script" to the ajax request. Thanks again Krishnar for the valuable help!

Answer (score 1):

```
@city_id = City.select('id').find_by_id(params[:city])
```

This line doesn't return you a number. It returns an instance of your model with only one field (id) loaded. Try to change it to

```
@city_id = City.select('id').find_by_id(params[:city]).id
```

That will give you a number.

Also, as I see, in your handler of AJAX in `$("#city_name").on('click')` you don't actually update your view with generated chart.

```
<%= j render(partial: 'city_stats') %>
```

This line gets evaluated only once, on initial rendering of the html page (that's why everything works when `city_id` is set manually), so on each AJAX request, that doesn't reload your page entirely, you replace `$('#stats')` with the same content.

By the way, once you replace `$('#stats')`, you will not access it the next time without total rerendering of the page, because it gets removed from the DOM. See reference of ([replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)).

I think that in case of AJAX it's better to use [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) on `$('#stats')` container and then [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) new chart inside it.

The idea is that if you want to update chart without reloading of the page, you should use the fresh data from the the server.

```
success: function(data) {
```

In your case it will be inside the `data` variable.

I see that in your controller you have this:

```
format.js { 
  render json: { 
    html: render_to_string(
      partial: 'city_stats', 
      locals: { 
        city_id: @city_id,
        spatial_ratio: @spatial_ratio
    }) 
  }
}
```

So you should use this data in your handler. It might be like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#stats').empty().append(data.html);
}
```

However, I'm not sure that it's reachable in current implementation. I guess that every time you make an AJAX request, it will end with

```
format.json  { render :json => @cities }
```

So you should either return both `@cities` and rendered partial here, and use them in relevant success callbacks, or somehow separate responses for each request.

One more thing about the code - it's not good to bind event handler for `$("#city_name")` inside change handler of `$("#city_state")`, because on every change of `$("#city_state")` you add the same handler for `$("#city_name")` click, and on each click this handler will be executed as many times as it has been bound. You can use [.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) before binding to prevent this, but maybe it's worth to do some refactoring.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Maksim, unfortunately that didn't solve the issue.. I got undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Also when I print the query I do see the city_id as a number

Comment: Here's the query on the terminal after I select a city  : SELECT COALESCE(name) as name, count(*) FROM (SELECT name, regs.segment_id, count(*) FROM regs
              INNER JOIN segments ON regs.segment_id = segments.id 
              WHERE regs.city_id = 354
              GROUP BY segment_id, name 
              ORDER BY count(*) DESC) as tabe 
              GROUP BY name;

Comment: Undefined method id for nil:NilClass means that Rails haven't found a record in the datatabase. Maybe there is something wrong in params[:city]?

Comment: Thanks a lot Maksim for your detailed answer! It help me understand some things. Although I'm still not able to solve the problem. I have a couple of questions. How can I render two objects in the same json? (@cities and @spatial_ratio) I tried putting them in a hash but it doesn't work.. As for your last remark regarding binding the event handler, could you please give me an example on how I can apply the optimization you've suggested?

Comment: @GeoSal About multiple objects in same json - yes, you need to add them to hash, under the different keys ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46521930/5565348)). And about binding an event handler - if it's possible, just do it outside of another event handler. If you have your selects rendered by the time you bind handler for `change`, why not to bind `click` handler for the second select on the same level? If it doesn't fit in your case, check other options :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!