# Rails multiple format.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

How can I write multiple format.json responses like:

```
def index 

  @books = Book.all
  @user = @books.map { |u| u.user }.uniq

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @books }
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end

end
```

in a better way?

Comment: so how output would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use multiple block for same format. If you want to render both `books` and `users` try sending them at once:

```
def index 

  @books = Book.all
  @user = @books.map { |u| u.user }.uniq

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: {books: @books, users: @user} }
  end

end
```